# How to add validation custom messages with array items rules when validating array in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

I've custom validation code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'array' => 'required|array|max:100',
    'array.*' => 'required|string|distinct|min:3'
], [
    'array.max' => 'Array can't have more :max items',
]);
```

**Here how I can add cusom message with array items rule?**

For example: `'array.item.min' => 'Array items length can't be greater :min charackters'`

Example laravel default validation error message for array items:

```
{
  message: "The given data was invalid."
}

errors: {
  array.3: ["The array.3 must be at least 3 characters."]
}

array.3: ["The array.3 must be at least 3 characters."]

0: "The array.3 must be at least 3 characters."
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

How I can replace this validation message with my single message for array items?

Comment: can you provide more code so i can understand better

Comment: I'm not sure, can you try `array.*.min`?

Comment: @aceraven777, it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding custom messages on each element when the form is submitted. Here's the sample code

```
$customMessages['array.max'] = "Array can't have more :max items";

foreach ($request->get('array') as $key => $value) {
    $customMessages['array.' . $key . '.min'] = "Array items length can't be greater :min characters";
}

$this->validate($request, [
    'array' => 'required|array|max:100',
    'array.*' => 'required|string|distinct|min:3'
], $customMessages);
```

If you want to show the error in your view, you can do this:

```
@if ($errors->has('array.0'))
    {{ $errors->first('array.0') }}
@endif
```

If you have foreach in the view

```
@if ($errors->has('array.'.$index))
    {{ $errors->first('array.'.$index) }}
@endif
```

Comment: How can I show then generated error message in your mean? @aceraven777

Comment: For example I will return error message and use it with javascript. Example  generated message in js: `skills.2: Array(1)`. Here array name is `skills.2`. Error with 2 item of array. Can you say your mean about showing error messages?

Comment: @aceraven77 you saved me.i wish i can like this answer a thousand times